# Updating View while running loop inside another class?

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

I have a loop that runs inside another class which doesn't reference my ViewModel.  I'm trying to figure out how I can update my View to provide updates about the current status of the while loop.  Is it possible to do this without passing in my ViewModel?

Property inside my ViewModel that updates the view:

```
 public int BeatNumber
        {
            get
            {
                return beatNumber;
            }
            set
            {
                if (beatNumber != value)
                {
                    this.beatNumber = value;
                    RaisePropertyChanged(() => BeatNumber);
                }
            }
        }
```

//BeatNumber inside this class needs to update the view

```
 class PatternSequencer
    {
           ....

            while (samplePos < sampleCount)
            {
                 BeatNumber++;

            }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

yes , by using the  [Events / Delegates](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/orm-9780596521066-01-17.aspx) which is .net implementation of Observer pattern or if you are using Prism / CAL then EventAgreegator can also help